# onkeyup javascript attribute set text in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this `TextArea`

```
  <textarea class="textarea" onkeyup="deltxtArea(1)" id="txtID1" placeholder="Remarks"></textarea>
```

and this `hidden text box`

```
  <input type="hidden" name="Textarea" id="txtArea" value="" required>
```

and this is my `JavaScript`

```
    function deltxtArea(id){
      var txtAreaValue = $('#txtID1').val();
      alert(txtAreaValue);
    }
```

As you can see here I used alert just to make sure that the `onkeyup` is working by getting the value of `textarea` and as of now it successfully gets the value of `textarea` and showing to the alert.

But when I tried to set the value of `textarea` to hidden textbox the script of `onkeyup` doesn't work anymore

This is the jQuery I used when I'm trying to set a text to a textbox

```
    $("#txtArea").val(txtAreaValue);
```

Comment: your code should work. How are you verifying if value is set or not?

Comment: I used inspect element and checks if the hidden textbox is changing its value when the onkeyup is triggered

Comment: inspect element will not show you the change as it will not change DOM on browser. You can check value using `console.log( $("#txtArea").val())`  or  `alert( $("#txtArea").val())`

Comment: I tried to alter the hidden input something like this `<input type="text" name="Textarea" id="txtArea" value="" style="display:none;">` but still ain't working. But showing the value of `textarea` using alert is showing weird

Comment: can you reproduce this issue on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function deltxtArea(){
      var txtAreaValue = document.getElementById('txtID1').value;
      
  document.getElementById('txtArea').value = txtAreaValue; 
    }
```

```html
<textarea class="textarea" onkeyup="deltxtArea()" id="txtID1" placeholder="Remarks"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="Textarea" id="txtArea" value="" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this context and remove the invoke ().

```
<textarea class="textarea" onkeyup="deltxtArea" id="txtID1" placeholder="Remarks"></textarea>
```

And into your script file, just do:

```
function deltxtArea(id){
  var txtAreaValue = $(this).val();
  $("#txtArea").val(txtAreaValue);
}
```

Or a better way, do your keyup event into the script file, and remove the inline attribute of your html:

```
function deltxtArea(id){
  var txtAreaValue = $(this).val();
  $("#txtArea").val(txtAreaValue);
}

$(function() {
  $("#txtID1").keyup(deltxtArea)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

All this looks fine but i think difficult to find the issue
I have tried as per your requirement all this looks fine , so kindly tried this code , you can avoid to include jquery if you already included

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <textarea class="textarea" onkeyup="deltxtArea(1)" id="txtID1" placeholder="Remarks"></textarea>
          <input type="text" name="Textarea" id="txtArea" value="" required>
          <script type="text/javascript">
               function deltxtArea(id){
                  var txtAreaValue = $('#txtID1').val();
                  alert(txtAreaValue);
                  $("#txtArea").val(txtAreaValue);
                }
          </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

if it works for you after that you can change input type from text to hidden